# Value of multiple struct variables is same unintentionally

Tags: c, struct

I have a code that does OOP like Java.
I have separated the interface and the implementation in separate files names `demo.h` and `demo.c`.

**demo.h**

```
#ifndef DEMO_H
#define DEMO_H



typedef struct {

    /* 
       This is the variable that will be set by setter method
       and its value will be extracted by getter method. 
       This variable must not be directly accessible by the programmer.
     */
    int num; 


    void (* setNum)(int);  // This function will set the value of variable "num".
    int (* getNum)();      // This function will return the value of variable "num".
} *Demo;  // As objects in java are always called by reference.



Demo newDemo();  // This function will create an instance of class(struct here) Demo and return.
/* This is equivalent to:

       Demo obj = new Demo();

   int java.

   I want my users to create instance of this class(struct here) like this:  

       Demo obj = newDemo();  

   here in this code.
 */


#endif
```

And the implementation:
**demo.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "demo.h"


Demo demo;  /* I have created a global variable so that it is accessible 
               in setNum and getNum functions. */



void setNum(int num) {

    demo->num = num;  // This is where the global demo is accessed.
}



int getNum(Demo obj) {

    return demo->num;  // This is where the global demo is accessed.
}



Demo newDemo() {

    Demo obj; // This will be the returned object.


    obj = (Demo)malloc(sizeof(*obj));  /* Allocating separate memory to 
                                          obj each time this function is called. */


    /* Setting the function pointer. */
    obj->setNum = setNum; 
    obj->getNum = getNum;

    /* As obj is at different memory location every time this function is called,
       I am assigning that new location the the global demo variable. So that each variable
       of the Demo class(struct here) must have a different object at different memory
       location. */
    demo = obj;

    return obj;  // Finally returning the object.
}
```

This is how I have implemented the `main` function:

**main.c**

```
#include "demo.h"
#include <stdio.h>



int main() {

    void displayData(Demo);


    Demo obj1 = newDemo();
    Demo obj2 = newDemo();
    Demo obj3 = newDemo();


    obj1->setNum(5);
    obj2->setNum(4);
    obj3->setNum(12);



    displayData(obj1);
    displayData(obj2);
    displayData(obj3);



    return 0;
}



void displayData(Demo obj) {

    int num = obj->getNum();

    fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", num);
}
```

On compilation and execution on my mac book pro:

```
> gcc -c demo.c
> gcc main.c demo.o -o Demo
> ./Demo
```

The output is:

```
12
12
12
```

But the desired output is:

```
5
4
12
```

What am I doing wrong?
Please help.
I don't want my users to pass the struct pointer as an argument as:

```
Demo obj = newDemo();
obj->setName(obj, "Aditya R.Singh"); /* Creating the program this way was successful as my 
                                        header file had the declaration as: 

                                            typedef struct demo {

                                               int num;
                                               void (* setNum)(struct demo, int); // This is what I don't desire.
                                               void (* getNum)(struct demo); // This is what I don't desire.
                                            } *Demo;    

                                        I want to keep it like the way it is in my current
                                        demo.h*/  

/* I don't want to pass obj as an argument. All I want to do this is this way. */
obj->setName("Aditya R.Singh");
```

Is there any way possible to do this and get the desired output?

Please help, thanks!

Comment: You're never setting the global `demo` anywhere. I think you expect C to set it for you in your `obj->setName` call, but it doesn't; C doesn't have methods.

Comment: "I have a code that does OOP like Java" -> stop right there. No you haven't; C doesn't support this. You *can* get OOP in C, but it will never look anything like Java's syntax. Code that *looks* like Java in C will inevitably either not use objects, or not use instance methods. Either way it won't be object-oriented.

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutely no idea of `c++`,  but in your code, I think, `demo = obj;` is the problem. `demo` is global, right? It will get overwritten with evety call to `newDemo()`.

*Side effect : Memory leak.*

Comment: So how should I get it working? As in it remains separate form separate objects and does not get overwritten?

Comment: @Aditya I don't think it is a good idea to implement like this, but if you want to know, consider having a global array and if required, use `realloc()` to manage the memory (dynamic case) or, use an index (static case).

Comment: And this is not C++. I know what C++ is. And I know that we can have method bodies in C++ in structs. But thats not possible in C. And hence, I am forced to have a function pointer in the struct. Ok this array idea is good.